# How to choose texts to use for "learning by reading"?

Tags: learning-methods

How to choose texts to use for "learning by reading"?

The style that one aims for?

However, how is one supposed to know whether the stuff that one reads is "good"?

Answer (score 1):

I started by reading news published by the national broudcasting companies (and the local free newspaper); they tell about the culture and tend to have non-awful, if not perfect, languages.

Another thing I start is whatever I would be reading about anyways, and know a lot about. In my case this was roleplaying game blogs. Here there is no quality control.

A third thing is whatever books I happen to find, maybe from a library, maybe somewhere else. Printed books do tend to go through some rounds of editing and have non-awful language.

I should note that I keep a high tolerance to not understanding. At first I was happy enough to just figure out what the subject matter was, and some words here and there. I did not take any pressure about the level of understanding I achieved, and read only as much as I cared to do. No stress, just the enjoyment of the puzzle of figuring out what is been written.

Answer (score -1):

I like to read children's books that I've read many times in a fluent (native) language, and from there upgrade the level of difficulty.